# I am trying to parse a list to a function, but the function only handles the first line in the list and ignores the rest

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing an program that takes a list of emails and checks them against a list of passwords. Not something big like a big brute force program that requires a multiprocessor engine or something, just something basic to learn with.

After running the program, it checks all the passwords in the list against just the first email in the list of emails from the email list. I have tried handling it using different functions including some ugly verbosity, but it's all the same.

```
E-mail List Tester
NB: This is for educational purpose only.


import sys
import imaplib


EMAILS_FILE = open('email_list.txt', 'r')

PASSWORD_FILE = open('pass_list.txt', 'r')

SUCCESS_FILE = open('success.txt', 'a')

EMAILS_FILE_LIST = []


def set_check(_emails):

    email = str(_emails)

    for passwords in PASSWORD_FILE:

        password = str(passwords)

        print "E-mail: %s\nPassword: %s" % (email,password)

for emails in EMAILS_FILE:
    EMAILS_FILE_LIST.append(emails)

for email_count in range(0, len(EMAILS_FILE_LIST)):
    set_check(EMAILS_FILE_LIST[email_count])
```

I expect each of the emails in the list to be tested against all passwords in the password list and then move on to the next email and the next until it reaches the end. But all it does is check the first email in the list and stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, file objects such as `EMAILS_FILE` and `PASSWORD_FILE` have a 'pointer' that indicates where in the file they are.  As you read data from the file, the pointer moves on within the file.  So if you read a line from the file, the pointer then moves to the start of the next line.

After running through the passwords in `PASSWORD_FILE` once, the file pointer for the passwords file is left pointing at the end of the file.  If you try running through the passwords file again, you will get no results because the pointer is already at the end of the file and so there are no more passwords to read.

The simplest fix is to add a line `PASSWORD_FILE.seek(0)` just above the line `for passwords in PASSWORD_FILE:`.  This ensures the file pointer within `PASSWORD_FILE` is reset back to the start of the file.

Comment: Thank you Luke, this is very enlightening. It works like my first "Hello world!". I will be sure to study more on your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `_emails` in a loop. For the each email to undergo each passwords. This means an exponential loop. Hope this helps

```
def set_check(_emails):
    for email in _emails:
        email = str(_emails)

        for passwords in PASSWORD_FILE:

            password = str(passwords)

            print "E-mail: %s\nPassword: %s" % (email,password)
```

Comment: Hi Arben, thank you for your response, I just checked your update, but it didn't fix the error. I have also tried being creative with the example you suggested, but still, nothing.